# python not recognizing new created files

Tags: python

I have a python script that will create a text file and then will run a command on this newly created file.

The problem is that the command line is not recognizing the newly created file and I'm getting an error that the file is empty.

my code is something like this:

`randomval` is a function that will create random characters and return them as a string.

```
text_file = open("test.txt", "w")
text_file.write(randomval(20,10))


# do something with the `test.txt` file
```

but I'm getting an error that the file test.txt is empty.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: have you closed the file `text_file.close()`

Comment: While we're at it, you should just always use `with open(...) as text_file:` as you can't forget to close it in this case, it's actually easier, and it works even if exceptions or nontrivial control flow happens.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because unless you flush or close the file, the OS will not write any data to the disk. To make sure that the file is closed, use the `with` statement:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(randomval(20,10))

print('Whoa, at this point the file descriptor is automatically closed!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to close the file:

```
br@ymir:~$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:04:36) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> file=open('foo.bar','w')
>>> file.write('42\n')
>>>  
[2]+  Stopped                 python
br@ymir:~$ cat foo.bar
br@ymir:~$ fg
python

>>> file.close()
>>> 
[2]+  Stopped                 python
br@ymir:~$ cat foo.bar
42
br@ymir:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

You should, at least, flush the buffer before trying to do something with your new file (`text_file.flush()`). The best would be to close the file and reopen it when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `f.close()` and then open it again as text_file = open("test.txt", "r")

Answer (score 1):

The stream to the file is still open!!!! Just try: `text_file.close()`